# Single SAML Azure AD SSO app to authenticate multiple Non AAD configured applications

Tags: .net, authentication, cookies, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to create an application where there would be a single SAML AAD SSO configured application which should authenticate multiple .NET apps(framework, core), these .NET apps have their own set of users, I am trying to authenticate users working in our organization with Azure SSO login and all the other users not within our org with forms authentication for that particular app(I want to redirect them to that particular app to login individually),

I have managed to add Azure AAD SSO in each of the individual apps, but the process to create the configuration has become too cumbersome as another team is managing the azure portal and we are trying to find a way to bypass that by just creating one individual app which would authenticate all the apps without individually configuring them with AAD, can this be possible?, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD has a gallery this contains thousands of pre-integrated applications that use SSO. This quickstarts uses an enterprises application named Azure AD SAML ToolKit as an example, but the concept applies for most pre-configured enterprises applications in the gallery.

If your provided email address is from the organization then you can redirect the user to Azure AD, otherwise you can redirect them to your custom Authentication.
If the user is an existing user in your Azure Active Directory tenant you can utilize [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to query and [confirm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso).